# Object Literal Property Value Shorthand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties, key, shorthand

When creating JavaScript factory functions I was taught that the return syntax looks like the below:

```
function FF(constructorArg) {
   var _privateName = constructorArg;

   var publicMessage = "Hello StackOverflow";

   function publicMethodGetName() {
      return _privateName;
   }

   return {
      publicMethodGetName: publicMethodGetName,
      publicMessage: publicMessage
   };
}
```

However, I've just noticed that I can simplify the return to the following:

```
 return { publicMethodGetName, publicMessage };
```

and it still works.

Are there any unintended side effects of using this simpler syntax or is it fine to use?

Comment: That's ES6 which won't work natively on older JS engines (older browsers, etc). See https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a shorthand syntax of defining object literal properties that was introduced by ECMAScript2015 (a.k.a. ES6). The only possible problem is environmental support. The environment should support this feature.

For supporting ES5-based environments you can use an ES6 transpiler and convert the code into ES5.

Answer (score 1):

This is new es6 syntax. Only some browsers will support it unless you are compiling to es5. See the compatibility table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer