# Set javascript object with variable names

Tags: javascript

Say I want to create an object like:

```
let blue = 2;
let red = 3;
let green = 4;
const test = {
  blue: blue,
  red: red,
  green: green,
}
```

Is there a way to declare the `const test` without going through and setting each variable like `blue: blue`?

Comment: Does [this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819621/object-literal-property-value-shorthand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```js
let blue = 2;
let red = 3;
let green = 4;

const test = { blue, red, green }
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern Javascript environments you can use a shorthand syntax that says that the key of an object is the same as the name of a local variable with the correct value.

Or more succinctly:

```
let blue = 2;
let red = 3;
let green = 4;
const test = { blue, red, green }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can do the following if I understood your question correctly:
The key will be the variable name itself

```
const test = {
  blue,
  red,
  green,
}
```